# Improving performance result of classification for severely imbalance data having abnormal skewed distribution

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, imbalanced-data

I have a large dataset D  which I balanced using under sampling method called RandomUnderSampler from imblearn package which reduce the class data with majority. The data have three classes: Yes (1), No (0), Unfinished (2).

This is the minimal 3d projection of the dataset after perform PCA on the balanced version of the dataset:[image]

I tried RandomForestClassifier,BaggingClassifier, KNN and MLP Classifier etc with some hyperparameter tuning even LocalOutlierFactor via sklearn package but I cannot get desired precision even if I am using balanced data.

I am sharing the HTML version of the code I have so far in the following link : https://imbalance-data-classification.netlify.app/

All I see from google search is to balance and try different classifier while tweaking the hyperparameter which is not working. I atleast need precision of 80% rather than existing 44% I got in some instance of MLPClassifier.

What can be done given this situation to improve the precision for predicting data which should be labelled as Yes or No.  My knowledge related to Machine and Deep Learning is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using genuine oversampling?

Your questions states you are oversampling by using an undersampling method, which will remove data points leaving less data for training which may be why your model is struggling.

I believe the oversampling functionality is built into imblearn so should be a quick experiment to try it.

https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html

Comment: It just downsample data belong to the class with majority. If you see my notebook link in the question, I tried to balance the dataset by downsampling

Comment: Also, I tried SMOTE but no mentionable  improvement in the performance

Comment: Yes but you can also oversample the minority classes (only in training set) which just repeats data points of minority classes. This means you don’t lose the overall data size. The link in my answer takes you to the function you need to replace your RandomUnderSampler with… it should be changed to RandonOverSampler

Comment: But won't it just create synthetic data points which actually might not represent the original Yes type data characteristics. In real life won't it create problem?

Comment: Yes it creates synthetic data points and this does risk overfitting, but if you haven't got a working classifier it is certainly worth a try to see if it helps, especially as it only need very minimal code changes!

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working. Now I am trying to train data with only 2 features. Still not working.